# Unable to initialize schema for hive3.1.2 using cygwin

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

**I am unable to initialize schema for hive3.1.2 using cygwin**

```
export HADOOP_HOME='/cygdrive/d/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0
export PATH=$PATH:HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HIVE_HOME='/cygdrive/d/hadoop/hive'
export PATH=$PATH:HIVE_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:HIVE_HOME/lib/*.jar
```

**Started hadoop by**
`$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.cmd`

**to initialise schema**
`$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema`

**the following is shown**

```
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema`
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

THE hive-site.xml in hive\conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
      <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
   </property>
      <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
      <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
   </property>
    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.enable,doAs</name>
      <description>Enable user impersonation for HiveServer2</description>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
      <value>NONE</value>
      <description>Client authentication types. NONE: no authentication check LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class)</description>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
      <value>True</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```